# I need the Index of the last item in a List, how?

Tags: c#

So, I've been searching for a while but didn't really find any results. 
For example I have this list:
`List<int> intList = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}`
And I want to output in my console "Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 1", that doesn't make it hard. But I want to be able to use User-inputted numbers, and for the last number it has to have the "and" before the number instead of the comma. The things I've tried so far resulted in the problem that any item with the same value also had the "and" instead of the comma.

Examples of what I've used in the if-statement in my for-loop that resulted in any equal values as last one also having the "and":
`if (intList[i] == intList.Last())`
`if(intList[i] == intList[intList.Count - 1])`

It seems logic to me why these didn't work, but understanding the problem and fixing it are still 2 different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join everything before the `.Last()` and than concatenate with `" and " + Last()` like:

```
 string result = intList.Count <= 1 ?
       string.Join(", ", intList) :
       string.Join(", ", intList.Take(intList.Count - 1)) + " and " + intList.Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes brute force is the way to go.  Consider something like this:

```
private string ConcatInts()
{
    List<int> intList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    var len = intList.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i < len - 1)
        {
            buffer.Append(", ");
        }
        else if (i == len - 1)
        {
            buffer.Append(", and ");
        }
        buffer.Append(intList[i].ToString());
    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

I usually don't like indexing into a List (I like to think of them as lists), but they do support indexing quite well.

Comment: What does "I like to think of them as lists" means? Do you mean an List of Lists? Is there any "bad" things for indexing in a list? I'd like to know.

Comment: @LouisGo: The typical access pattern for a list is to enumerate it, from start to finish (for a singly linked list) or perhaps in either direction (for a doubly-linked list).  Even if the implementation isn't based on a linked list, the one *always works* access pattern for a list is iteration.  Just like the one *always works* access pattern for an array is indexing.  Some list implementations have horrible performance when accessed by indexing.  The .NET `List<T>`, however, is backed by an array under the covers, so indexing works well.  In my mind, though, I stay away from indexing a list

Comment: I got your point. Thanks for the explanation. Was considering merely .Net `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> intList = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,1};
        System.Console.WriteLine("Elements: \r\n");
        for(int index =0; index < intList.Count-1; index++)
        {
            System.Console.Write(intList[index].ToString());
            System.Console.Write(", ");
        }
        if(intList.Count > 1)
            System.Console.Write("and ");
        if(intList.Count > 0)
            System.Console.Write(intList[intList.Count-1]);     
        else
            System.Console.Write("<<Empty List>>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be too efficient, you can cheat a little like this:

```
 var result = string.Join(", ", intList);
 var lastCommaIndex = result.LastIndexOf(',');
 if (lastCommaIndex > 0)
 {
     result = result.Substring(0, lastCommaIndex) + " and" + result.Substring(lastCommaIndex + 1);
 }
```

Otherwise, @Alexei Levenkov answer is roughly what I'd do. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a shallow copy of the original list using **GetRange** and exclude the last element.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> intList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
        List<int> allButLast = intList.GetRange(0, intList.Count - 1);
        string last = intList.Last().ToString();
        string allButLastString = string.Join(',', allButLast);
        Console.WriteLine($"{allButLastString} and {last}");
    }
```